# Solving a equation with a 2-form/bivector differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I was thinking about a problem and a bivector differential equation appeared, not sure how to start solving the issue.

I want to find parameterization of the n-sphere, we know the implicit equation of the sphere:

$$|x|^2 = 1$$

And for the 1-sphere (embeded in $\mathbb{R}^2$) it is easy to find a parameterization:

$$\frac{d}{dt}|x|^2 = 0$$
$$\left < \dot x, x \right > = 0$$

From this equation we found that $\dot x \bot x$, using Hodge dual operator $I=-e_1e_2$ we can find an orthogonal space for $x$ and its parametric equation:

$$\dot x = I x$$

> Note that in $\mathbb R^2$ and $Ix = -e_1e_2 (x^1 e_1 + x^2e_2) = -x^2e_1 + x^1e_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
>  0&  -1\\
>  1& 0
> \end{pmatrix}x $

We can find a solution:

$$x(t) = e^{It}x(0)$$

I am trying to find the 2-sphere similarly, using a bivector differential equation:

$$\partial_1 x \wedge \partial_2 x = I x $$

How could I start solving this?

Comment: My first thought would be to write $x = Ux(0,0)\widetilde U$ where $U$ is a scaled rotor and try to see what sort of equation we can derive for $U$. If you're willing to cheat a little we could also let $U$ be a rotor since we know $x$ is constrained to a sphere.

Comment: $\dot x\cdot x=0$ does not imply $\dot x=Ix$, but only $\dot x=f(t)\,Ix$ for some scalar function $f$. Adding a dimension, you should have $\partial_1 x\wedge\partial_2 x=f(t_1,t_2)\,Ix$ where $I$ is the trivector and $f$ is a scalar function. If you really want $f$ to be constant, then I think you're just looking for an area-preserving map of the sphere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-area_projection